# Saving a lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to open a device, but getting the following error:

```
> trellis.device(device="pdf", filename="runtime.pdf")
Error in device.call(...) : unused argument (filename = "runtime.pdf")
```

The same error does occur when I try to open a device with

> pdf(filename="c:/R/FSM/runtime.pdf")

Is there a package that I need to load into the library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct argument is `file` rather than `filename`, as in `pdf(file = "myfile.pdf")`. Other functions that open new devices do use the `filename` argument, such as `jpeg()`, so you need to check the help file. In general, the error that was returned `Error in ...: unused argument` indicates that an argument supplied in the function call is not part of the function.